# Opening BIDS and setting up a flat file connection upon a button click in an excel work book

Tags: excel, ssis, bids, vba

I am working on a project which has field names and length of the respective fields in excel workbook. I am very new to excel macro programing and I have least knowledge about this.

Here is the detailed description on what I am up to;

1. Field names are in column A and starts from row 6.
2. Length of the respective field names are in column C and start from row 6.
3. A button will be placed in the which has the above details.
4. Upon button click, read the columns A and C.
5. Open BIDS 2008.
6. Add a flat file connection manager.
7. Create the columns for added connection manager, with the field names and their respective lengths.

I want the above to be done via a excel macro code.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why must you have a button in excel do this?

Just [script the package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135946.aspx) c# (or whatever language) using the excel file as a sort of .ini/config file.